# Intermittent SSL/TLS Exception

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.2, cloudflare

I have a console application on a client's server running Windows Server 2012. The server has .Net Framework 4.7.2 installed and I have added the following line before the app makes a request to the web-services:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

This works perfectly 99.9% of the time EXCEPT every hour, on the hour. To monitor the console app, it sends a "heartbeat" to the web-service every 30 seconds. If this fails, an exception email is sent. What I see is that literally every hour e.g. 17:00, 18:00, 19:00 etc the following exception is thrown:

```
Error details below: 
{
  "ClassName": "System.Net.WebException",
  "Message": "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.",
  "Data": null,
  "InnerException": null,
  "HelpURL": null,
  "StackTraceString": " at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)\r\n 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpWebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)\r\n 
  at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)\r\n 
  at AppName.Heartbeat.Heartbeat(String arg_username, String arg_password, Int16 arg_format, String inputFileStream) in C:\\Users\\Dev\\source\\Repos\\--\\Web References\\Heartbeat\\Reference.cs:line 78\r\n 
  at AppName.Interface.Heartbeat.Submit() in C:\\Users\\Dev\\source\\Repos\\--\\Interface\\Heartbeat.cs:line 105",
  "RemoteStackTraceString": null,
  "RemoteStackIndex": 0,
  "ExceptionMethod": "8\nGetWebResponse\nSystem.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a\nSystem.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol\nSystem.Net.WebResponse GetWebResponse(System.Net.WebRequest)",
  "HResult": -2146233079,
  "Source": "System.Web.Services",
  "WatsonBuckets": null
}
```

The heartbeat is successfully sent 119 times an hour but consistently fails once an hour, on the hour.

For what it's worth, the web-service is behind CloudFlare and I've also verified the server time is correct.

What could be causing this exception? I do not see this exception being thrown by any of the other web-services that this app interfaces with.

Comment: Sounds like it is an issue with `cloudflare`! If the heartbeat works with every other service you have tried, and only fails with `cloudflare`, the culprit could be it.

Comment: "Every hour, on the hour xx:00 a web service fronted by CloudFlare will throw the following exception on the first execution, but all subsequent ones succeed", extract from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/15461)

Comment: Thanks @Chin.Udara that issue thread was an interesting read. I guess the OS won't get the update so I'll have to implement a workaround as I'm not ready to upgrade to CF Business yet!

Comment: Relevant patch https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/microsoft-security-advisory-update-to-improve-tls-session-resumption-interoperability-january-12-2016-9649be99-ad3f-93d1-21b8-a8475f884b60 it looks like it's available for 2012 and 2012 R2, and you should have been patched for that anyway, it's dated 2016, I hope you've had patches since then

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, this is a client's environment so it's not in my control. I will raise it with their HelpDesk and determine why it has not been applied and if can be done.

Comment: I'd suggest you cease working with clients who refuse to apply patches, it's not worth the aggro. There are so many major vulnerabilities discovered in the last six years that that system probably has holes like a sieve.